# How does one use a PIP installed package from GitHub in Command Prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the NTS Radio downloader (https://github.com/everdrone/nts) that is available on GitHub.

I have PIP installed all the requirements and the downloader itself. So now it's a matter of using the program to download these **free radio shows**.

To the best of my knowledge, the author of the program mentions one would have to type "nts" on a line in the command prompt with a valid link and press enter for the program to work. In other words, the act of writing "nts" will execute or import the program for the user to enter whatever it is one wants.

However, when I enter "nts" on the command prompt, I get the message that "nts" "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." So my question is, what should I enter in the command prompt so that it recalls, imports, or executes the downloader before or in addition to writing "nts" so I can make use of it?

Thank you!

Comment: did you actually install nts though? the github repor says to do `pip3 install nts-everdrone`

Comment: Yes, I've installed it, but how do I use it once it's installed? That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to install from a Github repository is:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/everdrone/nts"
```

Comment: How to import when programming?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The program/package has already been installed, how do I make use of it now in Command Prompt?

Comment: it's explained in repository README. 
 Just paste the episode url and it will be downloaded in your Downloads folder.

nts https://www.nts.live/shows/myshow/episodes/myepisode
 
  i try this and it worked. @a89q092c209c2-2c

Comment: That link doesn't link to a show, so that means you couldn't have downloaded an episode.

Comment: it's just an example link :).  nts https://www.nts.live/shows/rave-reparations/episodes/rave-reparations-9th-september-2021

Answer (score 0):

you can install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on your computer. by this you can clone the repository and install it.

1. go to the repository page on github and press on the button **code**. Copy the url
2. go to your command line and type: `git clone [copied url]`
3. type: `cd [name of cloned repository]`
4. type: `pip install .`

[here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone#:%7E:text=git%20clone%20is%20primarily%20used,copies%20an%20existing%20Git%20repository.) is a guide if you don't understand the git clone function or want to learn more about it
this should do it!